# Limitations of AKS Networking CNI with Overlay

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am currently investigating various AKS networking options that are available, and while researching  CNI with Overlay I found a table comparing Kubenet and CNI with Overlay. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-cni-overlay).

The part that I do not understand is **where does the limit of 1000 nodes come from**

The Kubenet is limited by 400 I assume by the number of routers in User-Defined Route Table. However, I am struggling to find the reason for 1000 nodes in the Azure CNI Overlay.

Screenshot from the docs:
[image: Screenshot of docs]

I deployed AKS with the CNI with Overlay option. The things that were deployed were:

1. Two managed identities (these don't play a role I assume)
2. A Load Balancer with 2 FrontendIP Configurations and two Backend Pools (aksOutboundBackendPool and another one called "kubernetes")

- I realized that when I deployed more nodes each backend pool list would grow with every node
- 2 FrontendIP Configurations are actually 1 configuration with Load Balancing rule (1st Public IP) and 1 configuration with Outbound rule (2nd Public IP)

3. A Virtual Machine Scale Set which acts as a backend pool
4. Network Security Group attached to the VMSS

I validated the limitations of Networking Related resources in Azure [Networking Limitations](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/includes/azure-virtual-network-limits.md) and also I spotted that when adding a new node pool there is this piece of information:
[image: Node Pool information]

Therefore, I don't know where does limit of 1000 nodes actually come from.